# The Gauss's law for gravitational field and the unit system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, units, gauss-law, dimensional-analysis

[image]

Here $g$ is the gravitational field, $G$ is the gravitational constant, and $M$ is the total mass in the volume $V$. I wonder if this formula holds for any unit system. That is, does the coefficient $4\pi$ hold true for any unit system such SI or cgs? The maxwell equations change their form with the unit system given. So I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The integral form of Newtonian gravitation as well as the differential form follows from Newton’s force law of gravity.  The 4 pi factor comes from the integration over a solid angle and is therefore independent of the units used.  The only time the equation would seem to change in form is if natural units are used.  In that case G would become 1.

Comment: In gravitational physics research, it is actually just as common (if not more common) to set $8 \pi G = 1$, which greatly simplifies the Einstein equation.